# how can i get all the parent <li> items within my code

Tags: javascript

I have following markup:

```
<ul class="MenuBarVertical" id="Ul1">
            <li id="MBVItem3732874">
                <div class="MainMenuBarBackgrounImage">
                    <a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%2D1.html">category 1</a></div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732879">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D1%2D1.html" tabindex="-1">page 1.1</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732880">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D1%2D2.html" tabindex="-1">page 1.2</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732881">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D1%2D3.html" tabindex="-1">page 1.3</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732882">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D1%2D4.html" tabindex="-1">page 1.4</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732883">
                        <a href="/1%2D5.html" tabindex="-1">1.5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="MBVItem3732875">
                <div class="MainMenuBarBackgrounImage">
                    <a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%2D2.html" tabindex="-1">category 2</a></div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732884">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D2%2D1.html" tabindex="-1">page 2.1</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732885">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D2%2D2.html" tabindex="-1">page 2.2</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732886">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D2%2D3.html" tabindex="-1">page 2.3</a></li>
                    <li id="SMBVItem3732887">
                        <a href="/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%2D2%2D4.html" tabindex="-1">page 2.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

I want to display all the `<li>` id's of the parent UL (but at the moment it display all of the `<li>` within the `<ul>`) using java script.

My code is:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var list = document.getElementById("Ul1");
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0, size = items.length; i < size; i++) {

        alert(items[i].parnetnode.id);

    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me and let me know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: mistypo for "parnetnode" ? it should be parentNode

Comment: you are right about the spelling problem but it dosnt do what i ask for instead it just displays the id "ul1"

Comment: you are fetching the parent node. so give an id to ul1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code's getting **all `<li>` tags within `#Ul1`**. When you iterate and call `items[i].parentNode.id`, some will give you the right ID, but some will give you `#Ul1`.

Instead, try getting just the second level `<ul>`, and then accessing the parent node's ID:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var list = document.getElementById("Ul1");
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("ul"); // <-- i.e. select #Ul1 ul
    for (var i = 0, size = items.length; i < size; i++) {
        alert(items[i].parentNode.id);
    }
}
```

*Note: This solution depends on the HTML structure you described, and works as long as there are no third (or deeper) level `<ul>` tags.*

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U5pNS/**

Answer (score 0):

Change your spelling parnetnode to `parentNode` and give an id to the parent "ul"

```
alert(items[i].parentNode.id);
```

Comment: it dosnt do what i ask for instead it just displays the id "ul1" , i need it to display only the id's that start with MBVItem373... and so on not the one's that start with SMBVItem3732